# Find a solution for partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The PDE is: $$u_t(x,t)+cu_x(x,t)=0$$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for every $t > 0$, with $u(x,0)=f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2 (\mathbb{R}) \cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

**What I have done:** I have used separation of variables, where we have:
$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$. Then, we arrange:

$$X(x)T'(t)=-cX'(x)T(t)$$
$$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-c \dfrac{X'(x)}{X(x)}=- \lambda$$

After integration of T and X, we have:

$$T(t)=e^{-\lambda t+c_1}$$ and $$X(x)=\dfrac{1}{-c}e^{-\lambda x+c_2}$$

We use the initial condition, where: $X(x)T(0)=f(x)$ which implies 
$f(x)=X(x)=\dfrac{1}{-c}e^{-\lambda x+c_2}$

Finally, we have: $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)=\dfrac{1}{-c}e^{-\lambda x+c_2}e^{-\lambda t+c_1}$. Let say, $c_1 + c_2 = c_3$ and $\dfrac{1}{-c}=c_4$ and solution is: $$u(x,t)=c_4 e^{-\lambda(x+t)+c_3}$$

Is this right solution of this PDE?

Comment: What conditions do you have on $c$? The PDE is not well-posed if $c>0$, hence the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

There are errors in your computation. The solution does not depend on $c$ or $f$. Look for a solution of the form $u(x,t)=\phi(x-c\,t)$. Then
$$
u_t+c\,u_x=-c\,\phi'+c\phi'=0.
$$
It follows that$u(x,t)=\phi(x-c\,t)$ is a solution for any $\phi$. Now impose the initial condition to find $\phi$.

Comment: Please can you be more specific in which step I did a mistake?

Comment: I don't know why you said $u_t - cu_x$ since I have written $u_t+cu_x$=0

Comment: Typo.${}{}{}{}$